# Is there a better way to use jquery to set the last radio button in a group to 'checked'?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Is there a better or more preferred way to auto-select the last radio button in a set (there are 4 buttons), using jQuery?

```
$(':radio[name=filter_option]:nth(3)').prop('checked', true);
```

This works, just curious if this proper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's certainly valid.  If more radio buttons might be added - but you know you always want the last item selected - you could use `last`:

```
$(':radio[name=filter_option]').last().prop('checked', true);
```

... or, if you will always know the value of the item you want to select (irrespective of order):

```
$(':radio[value=third]').prop('checked', true);
```

... alternatively, perhaps you could include a class or some other attribute in the input tag that distinguishes it.  i.e.:

```
$(':radio.autoselect').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thank you! In this case, there won't be anymore added. But good to know I can use the value as a selector. That's what I was having trouble finding.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, i found

```
 <div class="test1_active">
      <input type='radio' name='radio1' class='radioButton' />
      <input type='radio' name='radio1' class='radioButton' />
      <input type='radio' name='radio1' class='radioButton' />        
      <input type='radio' name='radio1' class='radioButton' />
    </div>

<script>
    $('.radioButton').last().prop('checked', true);
</script>
```

Enjoy the jsfiddle link  https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/cjh7bqdL/

cheers

Comment: Well thank you! That's what I was looking for. Man, I feel a little silly. HA!

Comment: Works Great! I selected the checkmark. I'm fairly new to the site so I can't upvote it (if I'm saying that correctly).